# jQuery document ready triggered before actually read

Tags: jquery

I put my  `$(document).ready()` code in the HEAD of the document, and inside it I have `alert($("#some-textbox").val())`, but this produces "undefined" when the page loads. However, If I move this code to the footer of the page, it works.

Code:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  var searchForm = $("#search-form");
  var searchBar = $("#search-bar");
  var INITIAL_TEXT = "Start typing to find friends or colleagues...";
  $(document).ready(function() {

      alert(searchBar.val()); // For testing purpose only; outputs undefined

      searchForm.submit(function(e) {
            if(searchBar.val() == INITIAL_TEXT) {
                searchBar.val("");
            }
      });
      searchBar.focus(function() {
            if(searchBar.val() == INITIAL_TEXT) {
                searchBar.val("");
            }
      });
      searchBar.blur(function() {
            if(searchBar.val() == "") {
                searchBar.val(INITIAL_TEXT);
            }
      });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: are you including jquery script before calling $(document).ready()?

Comment: yes. No error in the browser console

Comment: @FreemanLatif you should definitely post more code, otherwise this turns into a guessing game.

Comment: what happens if you try `window.onload=function(){//your code}`?

Comment: then it would be helpful to see your code

Comment: I tried $(window).load  as well, same result

Comment: @FreemanLatif, I meant the vanilla JS version

Comment: What happens if you move all vars in `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching the object outside the `doucment.ready` when the DOM hans't loaded yet.

move the entire code into the function.

Answer (score 5):

Your selector `$("some-textbox").val()` is invalid.

Did you mean

```
$(".some-textbox").val()
```

or

```
$("#some-textbox").val()
```

maybe?

**Update (question changed)**

You should move the variable definition inside the document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchForm = $("#search-form");
    var searchBar = $("#search-bar");
    //....
});
```

Comment: Yea that was a typo, sorry.

Comment: @FreemanLatif In that case you might have a duplicate ID in your html

Comment: Can't find any duplicates.. The problem is it works fine when I cut-paste the code to the footer instead. I used alert($("#some-textbox")) in the above code in the HEAD, and it gives me [Object object] so actually the object is loaded when the script runs. However, I can't access the val(), nor assign event handlers to them.